# The 'name' does not exist in the current context C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, evopdf

I was using the sample code for my project to export Html-pdf using EvoPdf converter. This is the If Else statement.

```
if (convertUrlRadioButton.Checked)
            {
                string url = urlTextBox.Text;
                outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrl(url);
            }
            else
            {
                string htmlString = htmlStringTextBox.Text;
                string baseUrl = baseUrlTextBox.Text;
                outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtml(htmlString, baseUrl);
            }
```

`The name convertUrlRadioButton does not exists in the current context`

I get this error, The name 'convertUrlRadioButton' does not exist in the current context.
What am I doing wrong?

I tried to generate a field object with the name `convertUrlRadioButton` but

`'type' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).`  This error occurs.

Comment: Is this from code-behind? `convertUrlRadioButton` should be a field of the class that code is from. Is it?

Comment: There might be a typo in : `convertUrlRadioButton` - basically the compiler is telling you your using a variable name which has not been defined. As an example: `int y = 0;` but referring to it as `y1 = 4;` , `y1` in that sense is not defined.

Comment: Stop application and right click on the button (in designer) and select properties.  The first row of the property window will give you the name of the button.